# Apple's NLTagger Sentiment analysis doesn't work with other languages

Tags: ios, swift, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm building a project with Apple's NaturalLanguage framework, I tried to execute Sentiment analysis with French language, but it surely doesn't recognise any word, but tokeniser recognises the language. Here is the code:

```
func emotionClassification(text: String) -> EmotionalStates {
        var numericScore: Double = 0
        let tagger = NLTagger(tagSchemes: [.tokenType, .sentimentScore])
        tagger.string = text
        
        tagger.enumerateTags(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, unit: .paragraph, scheme: .sentimentScore, options: []) { sentiment, _ in
            
            if let sentimentScore = sentiment {
                print(sentimentScore.rawValue)
                
                numericScore = Double(sentimentScore.rawValue)  ?? 0
            }
            
            return true
        }
        
        emotionScore = numericScore
        
        if numericScore <= -0.9 {
            return .bad
        }
        else if numericScore <= -0.5 {
            return .worried
        }
        else if numericScore <= 0.3 {
            return .calm
        }
        else {
            return .happy
        }
    }
```

"sentimentScore.rawValue" is always 0.0

Apple doesn't claim anywhere that other languages are not supported, so please help me resolve this issue.

I tried to tokenise string to detect language in this code and it defines it correctly

Comment: See `NLTagger.availableTagSchemes(for: .paragraph, language: .french)` and compare to `.english`.

Comment: gotta try, thanks)